# Leafletjs - large dataset

Tags: leaflet

I have a 11K endpoints that I need to place on the map. Rendering all of them crashes the browser, is there any workarounds that could be used e.g rendering while user moves around the map etc?

```
function createMap(center, zoom) {
  let map = L.map("map").setView(center, zoom);
  L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 19,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
  }).addTo(map);
  return map
};
```

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    let probes_map = createMap([45.5, -1], 4);
    let probes_locations = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("probes_coordinates_json").textContent);
    let markerFeatureGroup = L.featureGroup().addTo(probes_map);
    for (let probe of probes_locations) {
        let probeDescription = "BGP AS: " + String(probe.bgp_asn_number) + "<br> AS Name: " + probe.bgp_asn_name + "<br>Probe ID: " + String(probe.probe_id);
        L.marker(
            [probe.coordinates_latitude, probe.coordinates_longitude]).addTo(markerFeatureGroup).bindPopup(probeDescription, { maxWidth: 560 });
    };
});
```